# PHP Errors Cond and 1 more

Tags: php

currently Developing a website for my local isp, anyway they want a speed test, soo oolka net gauge is out of the question so i chose http://www.v-speed.eu I quite like their UI but anyway i get these errors on the main page

> Notice: Undefined index: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\speed\index.php on
>   line 48
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cond in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speed_class\class.core.php on line 961
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: cond in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speed_class\class.core.php on line 990
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\speed_class\class.core.php on line 1022

Couldn't figure it out
http://pastebin.com/s1tMEMaf

Just want to fix this
$sql = "
                SELECT
                    COUNT(`id`) AS `count`
                FROM
                    `boxes`
                WHERE
                    1 ".$cond."
                ORDER BY
                    `order` ASC
                ";

Comment: Read errors properly. you can solve it.. Read line numbers and check code at that line. Or atleast show your code. No can figure out whats on that line. Read this http://www.careerride.com/PHP-types-errors.aspx

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s1tMEMaf there you go, no i tried and i couldn't solve it, the one in index.html was a typo.

Comment: Did you write this code or downloaded it from somewhere. If you write this code then it should be very easy for you  to solve this error .. Its 2098 LOC.

Comment: I said i bought this speed testing code from v-speed.eu

Answer (score 0):

well You are using a variable ($cond) in a method where it is not defined yet. 
How are you suppose to append something to something that is not there. (starting on line 948 )

You might want to start with `$cond = "";`
or

```
 if($text) $cond = " AND (`name` LIKE :text)";
```

Your undefined offset on 1022 means that your probably  get NULL on a key that you are trying to get that does not exist.

As Rahul stated, you should read the error messages properly. The errors you mention tell a lot already and should give enough information for you to debug it.

Comment: Thanks, i have never used cond before so i did not know what it meant anyway thanks

Comment: $cond is just the variable name someone has given it ( stands for condition looking at the value that is given to it).

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'LIKE' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\speed\_class\class.core.php on line 961

got this error will be trying to fix it

Comment: if you cant help its okay


    Notice: Undefined index: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\speed\index.php on line 48

    Notice: Undefined variable: cond in C:\xampp\htdocs\speed\_class\class.core.php on line 961

ill be working

Comment: can you update your pastebin,seems like you are now missing smth

Comment: Oke. You might want to learn a little bit more about programming first. The way you changed the things now did not really make sense :) should have only changed `if($text) $cond .= " AND (`title` LIKE :text OR `text` LIKE :text)";` also your sql statement is now wrong..

Comment: #1 i bought this code
#2 i suck at php
#3 if you can help me fix this that'd be great